# How to arbitrarily center these drawings?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, graphs

I have adapted the following to draw lines from the center of a circle out to *n* equally spaced points on a circle (the *n* th roots of unity, or the points of an *n*-gon, or a star graph).

I need to be able to freely manipulate **EDIT:four** parameters:

1) the radius of the circle

2) the number *n*

3) the center of the circle.

**EDIT:**

**4) the angle of inclination of the star (i.e. ability to rotate star)**

With the LaTeX below I am able to do the first two, but I cannot center the circles. I need to be able to have the second circle centered at one of the points of the first circle, and I need to be able to do this *generally* (i.e. recursively, *n*-gon after *n*-gon, basically building rooted trees).

(I also need to be able to specify the colors of arbitrary  edges and points, as the LaTeX below shows -- I assume that any technique that solves my problem with 3) will not prevent me from doing this).

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
\documentclass[portrait]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,right=1in,left=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5.3,cap=round,>=latex]

    \foreach \x in {0,60,...,360} {
            % lines from center to point
            \draw[gray] (0cm,0cm) -- (\x:.1cm);
            % dots at each point
            \filldraw[black] (\x:.1cm) circle(0.2pt);
             }

\filldraw[black] (0,0) circle(0.2pt);
\filldraw[red] (0:.1cm) circle(0.2pt);
\draw[red] (0cm,0cm) -- (0:.1cm);      


\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5.3,cap=round,>=latex]

    \foreach \x in {0,120,...,360} {
            % lines from center to point
            \draw[gray] (0,0cm) -- (\x:.1cm);
            % dots at each point
            \filldraw[black] (\x:.1cm) circle(0.2pt);
    }

\filldraw[black] (0,0) circle(0.2pt);
\filldraw[red] (0:.1cm) circle(0.2pt);
\draw[red] (0cm,0cm) -- (0:.1cm);      


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for typing exercise with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}
\def\f(#1)#2#3#4{% 
    % #1: center
    % #2: radius
    % #3: point name prefix
    % #4: number of points
    \rput(#1){\curvepnodes[plotpoints=\numexpr#4+1]{0}{360}{#2 t PtoC}{#3}}%
    \multido{\i=0+1}{#4}{\psline{-*}(#1)(#3\i)}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(7,7)
    \f(1,1){3.5}{A}{10}
    \f(A1){2}{B}{6}
    \f(B1){.5}{C}{12}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit 3.1415926535

New features as follows are added

1. Rotation
2. Line color

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}
\def\f(#1)#2#3#4#5#6{% 
    % #1: center
    % #2: radius
    % #3: point name prefix
    % #4: number of points
    % #5: rotation
    % #6: color
    \rput(#1){\curvepnodes[plotpoints=\numexpr#4+1]{0}{360}{#2 t #5 add PtoC}{#3}}%
    \multido{\i=0+1}{#4}{\psline[linecolor=#6]{-*}(#1)(#3\i)}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(7,7)
    \f(1,1){3.5}{A}{10}{0}{red}
    \f(A1){2}{B}{6}{30}{green}
    \f(B1){.5}{C}{12}{90}{blue}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit 3.14159265358979

New features as follows are added

1. set a branch color individually
2. set a branch's  end color individually

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}
\def\f(#1)#2#3#4#5#6{% 
    % #1: center
    % #2: radius
    % #3: point name prefix
    % #4: number of points
    % #5: rotation
    % #6: color
    \rput(#1){\curvepnodes[plotpoints=\numexpr#4+1]{0}{360}{#2 t #5 add PtoC}{#3}}%
    \multido{\i=0+1}{#4}{\psline[linecolor=#6]{-*}(#1)(#3\i)}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(7,7)
    \f(1,1){3.5}{A}{10}{0}{lightgray}
    \f(A1){2}{B}{6}{30}{green}
    \f(B1){.5}{C}{12}{90}{blue}
    \psline[linecolor=orange]{-*}(1,1)(A3)
    \psline[linecolor=magenta]{*-*}(B1)(C6)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good answer (!) but can't you just write "a PSTricks solution" or similar instead of "typing exercise"; the latter sounds like it's almost too easy for you and thereby implicitly saying that others are 'stupid' since that haven't done it themselves.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: It is just an opening greeting that is not necessarily important. :-)

Comment: You make it look so simple! I don't know PSTricks at all -- looks like it's well named though. I wasn't able to reproduce your example, my interpreter crashed at \f(1,1){3.5}{A}{10} saying Undefined control sequence. I have the packages... don't know what's going on here. 

Also, I need the ability to color branches (possible?) and nodes selectively. (Perhaps by point name as you have defined it?)

Also, how would one rotate the star through an arbitrary angle? I realized after posting the question that I probably need this.

Comment: Is there any way to color the branches and nodes selectively? It looks like the stars are being colored globally here.

Comment: @Wapiti: It is always possible with PSTricks.

Comment: Most comprehensive with least code -- and I can center new stars on vertices BY NAME, without computing cosines and sines, which is the best. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

As a starting point, you can use tikzlibray `shapes.geometric`. Here is a minimal example how to use it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\r{2}%the radius of the circle
\def\n{6}%the number n
\def\x{0}%x coordinate of the center of the circle
\def\y{0}%y coordinate of the center of the circle
% create the node
\node at (\x,\y) [draw=none,minimum size=\r cm,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=\n] (a) {};

% draw a black dot in each vertex
\foreach \t in {1,2,...,\n}{
  \fill (a.corner \t) circle[radius=\r pt];
  \draw (a.center)--(a.corner \t);}
  \fill (a.center) circle[radius=\r pt];
  \draw [red] (a.center)--(a.corner \n);
  \filldraw [red] (a.corner \n) circle[radius=\r pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Very cool. I (kind of) know tikz, which is one thing I like about this answer. A question: Is there any way to alter the ORIENTATION of the regular polygon? For example, rotate the red arm / node above by some degree? I ask because the shapes.geometric package seems to give a default orientation that is not necessarily what I would want.

Comment: Sure, use, for example `rotate=30` in `\node` parameter. `\node at (\x,\y) [draw=none,minimum size=\r cm,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=\n,rotate=10] (a) {};`

Comment: I really like this. It seems however that rooting new stars at arbitrary locations might be difficult. Say I have a star rooted at the third point (some arbitrary point) on a 17 pointed polygon . It looks like I need to know the actual coordinate for this point, right? I need to say ' \node at (\x,\y) ' to center a star there.

Answer (score 2):

In the function `\myfunct`, there are three arguments.  The first argument is the angular increment between arms, 360/n if you will.  The second argument is the radius.  The third argument is the starting angle (where the red arm will lie).  Placement is accomplished by placing an instance of `\myfunct` at a specified nodal coordinate.

```
\documentclass[portrait]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,right=1in,left=1in]{geometry}
\newcounter{tmpcount}
\newcommand\myfunct[3]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5.3,cap=round,>=latex]
  \def\donefirst{F}
  \setcounter{tmpcount}{#1}
  \addtocounter{tmpcount}{#3}
    \foreach \x in {#3, \thetmpcount,...,\numexpr 359 + #3\relax} {
          \if F\donefirst
            \filldraw[red] (\x:#2) circle(0.2pt);
            \draw[red] (0cm,0cm) -- (\x:#2);  
            \gdef\donefirst{T}
          \else
            % lines from center to point
            \draw[gray] (0cm,0cm) -- (\x:#2);
            % dots at each point
            \filldraw[black] (\x:#2) circle(0.2pt);
           \fi
    }
  \filldraw[black] (0,0) circle(0.2pt);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(0cm,0cm) node [anchor = center] {\myfunct{15}{.3cm}{97}};
\draw(-.19cm,1.59cm) node [anchor = center] {\myfunct{60}{.2cm}{12}};
\draw(0.83cm,1.96cm) node [anchor = center] {\myfunct{120}{.13cm}{87}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

ADDITIONAL THOUGHTS:

I apologize for not knowing `tikz` other than by trial and error, but my intent to allow you to transfer from one figure to the next *automatically* is sketched in this code below.  If I could somehow turn what I call `\dx` and `\dy` into actual lengths, I could increment the "working center" of the figure with each call to `\myfunct`.  As you see in the final calls, I can (for a single call only), invoke `\dx` and `\dy` to serve as the new "working center" of my figure.  But my skills are limited at this point to proceed further.  Someone knowing `tikz` could probably click a few keys and bring it to life.

The other quirk with these additional thoughts is that in order for the center of the star to *always* lie at the center node (it won't normally if there are an odd number of spokes), I drew a thin white circle around the perimeter of the star.  This, of course, overwrites any underlying figure slightly, but I don't know a way to draw a "clear" circle, but I'm sure `tikz` can do so.

```
\documentclass[portrait]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,right=1in,left=1in]{geometry}
\newcounter{tmpcount}
\newcommand\myfunct[3]{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\cs{cos{#3}}%
  \gdef\dx{#2*cos(#3)}% NOT SURE HOW TO INCORPORATE THESE INTO LENGTHS
  \gdef\dy{#2*sin(#3)}% NOT SURE HOW TO INCORPORATE THESE INTO LENGTHS
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,cap=round,>=latex]
  \def\donefirst{F}
  \setcounter{tmpcount}{#1}
  \addtocounter{tmpcount}{#3}
  \draw[white](0:0) circle(#2);
    \foreach \x in {#3, \thetmpcount,...,\numexpr 359 + #3\relax} {
          \if F\donefirst
            \filldraw[red] (\x:#2) circle(1pt);
            \draw[red] (0cm,0cm) -- (\x:#2);  
            \gdef\donefirst{T}
          \else
            % lines from center to point
            \draw[gray] (0cm,0cm) -- (\x:#2);
            % dots at each point
            \filldraw[black] (\x:#2) circle(1pt);
           \fi
    }
  \filldraw[black] (0,0) circle(1pt);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(0cm,0cm) node [anchor = center] {\myfunct{15}{1.59cm}{97}};
\draw({\dx},{\dy}) node [anchor = center] {\myfunct{60}{1.06cm}{12}};
\draw(0.85cm,1.82cm) node [anchor = center] {\myfunct{120}{.72cm}{94}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's very helpful to see this code, since I need to learn this sort of stuff in tikz (I'm making a bunch of really complicated designs). Thanks for your comments on my question!